# GPRS Device and Azure IOT Hub issue

Tags: azure, iot, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

We are developing a system in which several devices equipped with Simcom SIM800 GPRS modules need to send telemetry data to an IoT Hub at port 443 using the AT command for GET & POST data to Azure REST API endpoint.

> https://{IoTHubName}.azure-devices.net/devices/{deviceId}/messages/events?api-version={api-version}

**Problem:** We got the *message successfully* at IOT end. But at device end we always got Status Code **600**.

**Note:**

**1.** We are able to Get & Post from any other REST Api using AT command, which we are host in Azure & able to get status code 200.

**2.** We call our own REST service via AT command, which is host in Azure, purpose of this service to post data into IOT Hub using azure C# SDK. We get status 200.

**3.** We can not use Azure C SDK due to device incompatibility. so we using IOT Hub Rest API call via AT command.

Comment: Are you saying you are getting a HTTP 600 status code? Because I thought there is no higher ones than 5xx?

Comment: @juunas : yes HTTP 600 status code. And this is the confusion why I am getting this !!!, because message posted successfully at IOT Hub end.

Comment: I am a beginner but 443 for MQTT protocol on Websockets, whats the protocol you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved after update Simcom SIM800 GPRS modules which support https.